# Scoped service DI & GC in .net CORE - Clarification?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, garbage-collection

My `Startup.cs` file is :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<IFoo,Foo>();   // Notice Scoped service
        }
```

Please notice that `IFoo` is a scoped service.

`IFoo` is a simple service :

```
 public interface IFoo
    {
        public int Get(int id)
        {
            return id;
        }
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
    }
```

And here is the simple contoller :

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;


    private readonly IFoo _fooService;

    public WeatherForecastController(IFoo fooService, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _fooService = fooService;
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<int[]> Get()
    {
        async Task Foo()
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(4000);
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                Console.WriteLine("***Service******" + _fooService.Get(4));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e);
            }
        }

        Foo(); // non awaitable
        return new[] { 0 };
    }
}
```

Please notice that `Foo()` is without `await`.

Now, When I run the code , I DO see the result of the scoped service being accessed after the request has completed ( since `Foo` is not awaited) :

[image]

I was expecting to see Null reference exception since it's a scoped service that is executed a long time after the main request thread has executed.

MSDN :

[image]
**Question:**

Why am I not getting a null reference exception?
Scoped service is only per request. and the request has finished long time before it was accessed by the task.

Comment: The controller will not get disposed until `Foo` completes. That means, the request is no complete yet.

Comment: @atiyar, you are not right, the controller action Get completes before Foo completes

Comment: @JesúsLópez Yes, but that doesn't mean that the controller is disposed.

Comment: @atiyar yes it is indeed. The request is finished and the scope disposed, therefore the controller is disposed as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scoped services are disposed when the scope is disposed, that doesn't mean that all references to scoped services become null. That means that the scope calls Dispose() method on all disposable objects that are created inside the scope. When you call a method on an object that has been disposed the object should raise `ObjectDisposedException`, you should not get `NullReferenceException`.

Try with the following and you will see that `ObjectDisposedException` is thrown:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    public int Get(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}

public class Foo: IFoo, IDisposable
{

    public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!IsDisposed)
        {
            IsDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (IsDisposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(Foo));
    }

    public int Get(int id)
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        return id;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: So how can i know if it's safe to use scoped services within task.run ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir You should not use scoped services outside the scope. You are doing it.

Comment: What do you mean by  " you are doing it" ? So you mean in my example ? So my example should not he used ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir You are calling a scoped service after the scope is disposed